# On budget travel from Orlando Florida to Lake Charles LA

Tags: budget, solo-travel, low-cost-carriers, florida

What is the most economical way to travel from Orlando-Florida to Lake Charles-Louisiana,
I am travelling on my own. I can compromise in terms of the trip duration and level of comfort if I can cut my expenses.

I am planning to go somewhere between 5-12-14 and 10-12 and come back around the 20th of December.

Thx.

Comment: Have you considered hitchhiking?

Comment: I don't think it is safe those days, is not it?

Comment: Gas is cheaper than it's been in years; you could just drive.

Comment: @pnuts no there is no thing specific about that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I see what u mean. I think that would be my best option so far.

Comment: @Anderson Iffy.  But it's cheap

Comment: IF you do decide hitching might be worth a go, you'll find http://hitchwiki.org/en/United_States_of_America useful

Comment: Much appreciated advises, I will take a look into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of hitchhicking your cheapest bet it to take the bus and train:

$167 total: Megabus at 7:40p from Orlando overnight to New Orleans arriving 6:15a ($15 for 5-Dec), continuing onward from New Orleans at 9:00a on Amtrak train, arriving Lake Charles 13:15p ($36 for 6-Dec). The sooner you can return the cheaper since tickets are more expensive near Christmas, "around the 20th" is vague, if you can leave on the 17th you'll save money. The Amtrak train back to New Orleans the afternoon of the 20th is $36 and the megabus overnight back to Orlando is $80.

$184 round trip: Greyhound has a direct bus Orlando to Lake Charles on Dec-5.

$274 round trip: [Tornado bus company](http://www.tornadobus.com/) van form Orlando to Plant City, from there they have a direct bus to Lake Charles.

The prices mentioned here all require advanced booking and will go up as the departure date nears.

Comment: This solves it for me.